# finding variables in textboxes

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have an issue when using textboxes that contains variables in word2016.

I would like to preform a search for a variable that may exist within textbox's text, and during certain instances I would like to replace it with a new variable. An example textbox is shown below :

[image]

I want to search for the DOCPROPERTY "Checked By". This DOCPROPERTY does not exist in the textbox but the text "Checked By" does , but my code as attached below finds it regardless. Since it is not a DOCPROPERTY, it should not return true.

```
' ************************************************************
' ********* finding docproperties in text, headers and textboxes
' **************************************************************
Public Function findProperty(doc As Document, findText As String) As Boolean
    Dim rngStory As word.Range
    Dim oFld As word.Field
    Dim objShape As Shape
    Dim temp As String
    Dim temp2() As String
    Dim element As Variant

    ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = True
    If findText = "_DocumentTitle" Then
        findProperty = True
        Exit Function
    End If

    findProperty = False


    For Each objShape In ActiveDocument.Shapes
        If objShape.Type = msoTextBox Then
            'do the required action
            temp2 = Split(objShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, "DOCPROPERTY")
            For Each element In temp2
                temp = replace(element, "DOCPROPERTY", "")
                temp = replace(temp, "\* MERGEFORMAT", "")
                temp = replace(temp, """", "")
                If InStr(UCase(temp), Trim(UCase(findText))) > 0 Then
                  findProperty = True
                  Exit Function
                End If
            Next

        End If
    Next objShape

    For Each rngStory In doc.StoryRanges
      Do
        For Each oFld In rngStory.Fields
          'If oFld.Type = wdFieldDocProperty Then
              'Dig a little deeper and see what the field code contains.
              'Formatting of property is a pain....
              temp = replace(oFld.Code.Text, "DOCPROPERTY", "")
              temp = replace(temp, "\* MERGEFORMAT", "")
              temp = replace(temp, """", "")
              If Trim(UCase(temp)) = Trim(UCase(findText)) Then
                findProperty = True
                Exit Function
              End If

        Next oFld
        Set rngStory = rngStory.NextStoryRange
      Loop Until rngStory Is Nothing
    Next rngStory
    ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = False
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You're splitting a string into an array using `"DOCPROPERTY"` as the delimiter, so there is no need to replace "DOCPROPERTY" with vbNullString, ("").

```
        temp2 = Split(objShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, "DOCPROPERTY")
        For Each element In temp2
            temp = replace(element, "DOCPROPERTY", "")
```

I think that you can test the size of `temp2`, if it is bigger than `0` then there was a `"DOCPROPERTY"` found, if it is `0` then there was no `"DOCPROPERTY"` found.

```
if UBound(temp2) > 0 then findProperty = True
```

But probably a better way is to look at Field(n).code which returns the field code text and then you know exactly what you have...

Answer (score 0):

With the suggestion from @SlowLearner is the working code presented below.

```
Public Function findProperty(doc As Document, findText As String) As Boolean
    Dim rngStory As word.Range
    Dim oFld As word.Field
    Dim objShape As Shape
    Dim element As Variant

    findProperty = False 'default false
    '**************************************************************************************
    '**************** ALL DOCUMENTS NEED A TITLE EVEN IF ITS NOT IN USE *******************
    '**************************************************************************************
    If findText = "_DocumentTitle" Then
        findProperty = True
        Exit Function
    End If


    For Each objShape In ActiveDocument.Shapes
        If objShape.Type = msoTextBox Then
            'do the required action
            For Each element In objShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Fields
                If InStr(UCase(element.Code.Text), Trim(UCase(findText))) > 0 Then
                  findProperty = True
                  Exit Function
                End If
            Next element
        End If
    Next objShape

    For Each rngStory In doc.StoryRanges
      Do
        For Each oFld In rngStory.Fields
              'Dig a little deeper and see what the field code contains.
              If InStr(UCase(oFld.Code.Text), Trim(UCase(findText))) > 0 Then
                findProperty = True
                Exit Function
              End If

        Next oFld
        Set rngStory = rngStory.NextStoryRange
      Loop Until rngStory Is Nothing
    Next rngStory

End Function
```

Comment: Glad to help. If everything is working please accept the answer as a solution (or ask for more information) 